# How can I modify a hosting database if is not possible to reach it remotely?

Tags: c#, web-services, api-design

I have to develop a desktop app, this app has to be able to connect into a hosted database (ipage.com) im order to get and insert data, the problem is that I can not reach the database remotely, so I don't know what to do, what do you guys recommend me to do?

note: I can't reach it because the webhost doesn't allow remotely connection.

Thanks.

Comment: Who is hosting this for you? Sometimes this is a simple setting.

Comment: If you are not able to connect to the database remotely, you will have to have some sort of service on the server itself to handle the inserting/updating data for you. Then the traffic is "local" to the database, and you will be able to connect.

Comment: So, I have to create a sort of web service kind of thing? can you guide me into it?

Answer (score 0):

As dub stylee write, you'll need to write an API which you'll make available from a webserver that does have database access. Then instead of making direct database calls your application will access the API, authenticate, and the API will make the database calls and return information on behalf of your application.

Answer (score -1):

from what I understand that you sometimes can't reach the database due to net connection problem

if that so

you may create a copy of the database locally and when the app reconnect to internet again it sync the databases

if not can you give a little more details

Comment: I can't reach it because the webhost doesn't allow it

Comment: aha I can't help you with that I didn't try to host database yet^^

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a local database and whenver you get a chance to connect with the remote database need to sync data through jobs or sp's